# Java Mapping ArrayList to HashMap

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have page gets given an ArrayList<Document> where each document has a property called type.

I don't know the number of unique types or documents.

I want to sort this ArrayList into a HashMap<type, document[]> but am having some trouble getting my head around it.

Some pseudo-code would like like

```
for (int i = 0; i < documents.size(); i++) 
{
   if there is an array for documents[i].type
   add to this array
   else create a new array for this type
   add document[i].type and the array of documents with matching type to the hashmap
}
```

I know this is the wrong approach and clearly won't work. I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// create the map to store stuff, note I'm using a List instead of an array
// in my opinion it's a bit cleaner
Map<String, List<Document>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Document>>();

// now iterate through each document
for(Document d : documents){

    // check to see if this type is already known
    List<Document> list = map.get(d.type);

    if(list == null){
        // list is null when it wasn't found in the map
        // this is a new type, create a new list
        list = new ArrayList<Document>();

        // store the list in the map
        map.put(d.type, list);
    }

    // finally, whether we got a hit or a miss, we want
    // to add this document to the list for this type
    list.add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think rather than *sorting* by type, the term you're looking for is *indexing* by type. [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface is designed for mapping keys to multiple values without all the hassle of dealing with the collections of values. In particular, Guava has a method that's designed to do exactly what you're trying to do:

```
List<Document> documents = ...
ImmutableListMultimap<Type, Document> typeIndex = Multimaps.index(documents,
    new Function<Document, Type>() {
      public Type apply(Document input) {
        return input.getType();
      }
    });

for(Type type : typeIndex.keySet()) {
  ImmutableList<Document> documentsWithType = typeIndex.get(type);
  ...
}
```

This is pretty much the same as doing:

```
ListMultimap<Type, Document> typeIndex = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for(Document document : documents) {
  typeIndex.put(document.getType(), document);
}
```

except that the resulting multimap is immutable. Note also that the above is almost exactly equivalent to Mark's example.